# How to get other column's value of the same row using textfinder()?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this particular code that already works to find a user's row using a inputted text, say input user1 has been found in row 1 and thus returns 1. However, this time I want to grab another columns value of the same row, the email column for example, and not just the row ID. How can I turn this code to return the user's email instead.

```
   var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
   var thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName("users");
   var tf = thisSheet.createTextFinder("user1");
   var userID = tf.findNext().getRowIndex();
   return userID;
```

I tried adding .getValues() after the .getRowIndex() but it results in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

About `I tried adding .getValues() after the .getRowIndex() but it results in an error.`, `getRowIndex()` doesn't return Range Object. By this, an error occurs. In this case, the Range Object can be retrieved from `findNext()`.

#### From:

```
var userID = tf.findNext().getRowIndex();
```

#### To:

```
var userID = tf.findNext().getValues()[0];
```

- By this modification, for example, when the email address is put to column "B", you can retrieve it by `userID[1]`.

#### Note:

- By the way, when the column of `user1` is the column "A", I think that the following modification might be able to be used.

  ```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName("users");
    var tf = thisSheet.getRange("A2:A" + thisSheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("user1");
    var userID = tf.findNext().offset(0, 0, 1, thisSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  ```

#### Reference:

- [findNext()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findNext())

Comment: The code in the note section of your answer worls but only for columns that start with the text that was search for and the remaining columns to the left. For example, rowID column goes at A, username at column B, and email at column C. If the username is the text that was searched. it will only output username and email for that row and not the rowID at column A. Is there a way to output the whole row's contents?

Comment: @codeTester- Thank you for replying. From your reply, you tested my 1st modification point? Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your tested script. And, about `Is there a way to ouput the whole row's contents?`, in my proposed 2 patterns, the searched row value is returned. So, I cannot understand your current issue. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the detail of your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: No need to be sorry at all for your English skills. I appreciate your effort.

For example, i search for createTextFinder("user1") and in my database the columns are:

Column A = rowID
Column B = username
Column C = Email

. Right now the function will only return ['user1', 'user1@mail.com'] which is column B and column C but I am asking if it is possible to return all the columns in the whole row and not just the text that was search like it should return ['1', 'user1', 'user1@mail.com'].

Comment: @codeTester- Thank you for replying. In my proposed script, the whole values of the searched row like `['1', 'user1', 'user1@mail.com']` in your reply is retrieved. Is this your expected value?

Comment: yes that is my expected return value.

Comment: @codeTester- Thank you for replying. From `yes that is my expected return value.`, when you tested my proposed script, I think that such a value is returned. So, I cannot understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: Because when I search for user1, it only returns ['user1', 'user1@mail.com'] which is column B and column C since column B is where 'user1' is found. Is there a way to return ['1', 'user1', 'user1@mail.com'] to start from the first column A and not just the column B where the 'user1' is found.

Comment: @codeTester- Thank you for replying. From `Because when I search for user1, it only returns ['user1', 'user1@mail.com'] which is column B and column C since column B is where 'user1' is found. Is there a way to return ['1', 'user1', 'user1@mail.com'] to start from the first column A and not just the column B where the 'user1' is found.`, in this case, I think that it is required to know your current situation using your sample Spreadsheet including your current script. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I got it now. I used offset(0, -1, 1, thisSheet.getLastColumn()) to begin with the columns that are on the left side of the search text. Thank you so much for your help, you helped me twice now. I deeply appreciate your effort.

Comment: @codeTester- Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your issue was resolved. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.